# is the a better more elegant/efficient way to write this piece of code

Tags: excel, vba

I was thinking since the constant here is cell B5, and i am checking it against 3 different values each giving a different outcome, is there a smarter way i can write this?

The main reasons i'm asking is because 1 i am actually interested in the answer (i am only 4 days old at coding) i want to learn as much as possible. and 2 because these are the only 3 changes the sheet makes and each time there is a change there is a flicker you can see it because i have shapes which flash every time there is a sheet change. if i delete the screen updating line there are multiple mini flashes, honestly i cant decide which one is least distracting.

### Edit: I have added my revised code thanks a lot @jamheadart @dwirony it looks so much better and runs nice and smooth apart from when it adds and removes columns it still flickers, i removed this bit and let it just change borders and it didn't flicker so it definitely is the hiding and unhiding that is the issue. anyone got any ideas? im starting to believe its just normal

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call UnlockSheet

    If Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5") = "Hours" Then
        Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        With Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        End With
        With Range("AV3:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
        End With
    Else
        If Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5") = "Weeks" Then
            Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            With Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
        End If
        If Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5") = "Days" Then
            Range("AU:AV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Range("AW:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            With Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
        End If
    End If

    Call LockSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address <> "$B$3" Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Call UnlockSheet

    Select Case Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5").Value
        Case "Hours"
            Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            Range("AV3:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
            Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case "Days"
            Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
            Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 1
            Range("AU:AV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Range("AW:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case "Weeks"
            Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        Case Else
            Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End Select

    Call LockSheet

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this in the module for `Calendar` worksheet?

Comment: I see you have self answered many of your questions, which is awesome.  You should go back and mark them and other answers to your questions as correct, those that you ended up using to solve your question, so that future readers know what worked for you when they visit that page.  Again it is great to see you coming back when you were able to solve the issue on your own so future readers can be edified.

Comment: Sorry @Scott i know i should be doing that and i have tried to look for where i mark them as correct but i literally can't see the option lol maybe you could help

Comment: There are check marks by the answer.  click on the one that you used that answered your question, including the ones you self answered.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Flickering when hiding/showing columns can be unavoidable on older versions. I'm using 2010 and get little graphical blips. If you've got a lot of data in the columns and formulae on the sheet then yes, it may be considered normal. I would ask a separate question about minimising Excel screen flickering when showing columns. But later versions are much better at handling the graphics, 2016 is pretty smooth!

Comment: yeh im on 2010, im only hiding 3 columns max though with 5 rows of data so at most 15 cells

Comment: That must be frustrating if the flickering is very obvious. I guess it might be machine and OS specific too cos it really shouldn't be an issue hiding a couple of columns with just a few rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your if-else statements by using `elseif` to make it a little cleaner:

```
Sub example1()
    If Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5").Value = "Hours" Then
        'do something
    ElseIf Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5").Value = "Days" Then
        'do something else
    ElseIf Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5").Value = "Weeks" Then
        'do a third thing
    Else
        'do something if range("B5") isn't any of those values
    End If
End Sub
```

But actually, you can replace this with a `select case` statment so you literally only refer to `B5` once:

```
Sub example2()
Select Case Sheets("Calendar").Range("B5").Value
    Case "Hours"
        'do something
    Case "Days"
        'do something else
    Case "Weeks"
        'do a third thing
    Case Else
        'do something if range("B5") isn't any of those values
End Select
End Sub
```

But your flickering problem is actually something else. It's because you're making changes to the sheet that triggers changes to the sheet...

It's a circular reference thing going on. I think you need to disable the worksheet change event while the worksheet has your automated changes on it and then re-enable the event at the end.

Or as hinted at in some other answers, your worksheet change routine can have range selection definition too

e.g. I always do a select case statement for the target range addresses:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
    Case "B5"
        ' call the routine with all your if-else and change logic here
    Case "Z55"
        ' do other things
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: wow the last bit of your post just clicked and i actually understand what you mean, i think this absolutely has to be the issue! This makes sense now why when i add a row on a different sheet which i do with selection change it doesnt flicker but it does flicker when i delete a row, which is done by sheet change.

 i tried to put code inside of case "B5" but it isn't working. If it helps B5 gets its value depending on what is selected from a list in B3.

I already incorporated the first part of your post, see the edit on my question

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of all the `With`s and just use one for `Worksheets("Calendar")`, also you only need 1 `If/ElseIf/Else` here - no need for nested `If`s:

Also, you need `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent recursion - if your worksheet changes, it'll keep triggering the event over and over.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address <> "$B$5" Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call UnlockSheet

    With Worksheets("Calendar")

        If .Range("B5") = "Hours" Then

            .Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            .Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            .Range("AV3:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot

        ElseIf .Range("B5") = "Weeks" Then

            .Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            .Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
            .Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 1

        ElseIf .Range("B5") = "Days" Then

            .Range("AU:AV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            .Range("AW:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            .Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
            .Range("AV2:AV8").Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 1

        End If

    End With

    Call LockSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow i didn't even know ElseIf was a thing! So when you say With Worksheets ("Calender") can anything inside only be relating to that worksheet?

Comment: Only lines that start with the period will refer to that `Worksheets("Calendar")`. You can still fully qualify a line with `Worksheets("Othersheet")` inside that `With` and that will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call UnlockSheet


    With Worksheets("Calendar")
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then 'Only run if B5 is changed otherwise skip.
            .Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            .Range("AU:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = .Range("B5") = "Weeks"
            .Range("AW:AW").EntireColumn.Hidden = .Range("B5") = "Days"
            With .Range("AV2:AV8")
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
                If .Range("B5") = "Hours" Then
                    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                Else
                    With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Weight = xlThin
                        .ColorIndex = 1
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With


    Call LockSheet
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. I think OP also needs something like `If Target.Address <> "$B$5" Then Exit Sub` at the top to avoid unnecessary run-time.

Comment: Bro this code is smooth af with everything else on my screen, but it isn't hiding/unhiding any of the columns. Also i forgot i actually gave cell B5 in a name in the name manager called "Time", could we use that instead of B5?

Comment: @ChrisR see edit, I took out the `.EntireColumn` in error.

Comment: hmm ok i took the not out of if not and it works, sadly it still flickers when a column is hidden/unhiden, but everything else runs a lot smoother

Comment: I'm 99% sure jamheadart is correct in what he is saying about using selection change instead of sheet change (making a sheet change to create another sheet change). I am struggling to get your code working inside (any code but i want yours) i make the selection in cell b3 in the form of a list, and b5 changes based on the value selected in he list, and columns hide/unhide based on b5's value

Comment: Cells changes by formula will not trigger the change event. If it is b3 that is changes by the user put the not back in and change the b5 in that line to b3. @ChrisR

Comment: cell b5 gets its value from "=INDEX(TblEmployeeList[#All],MATCH(Name,TblEmployeeList[[#All],[Name and Surname]],0),5)". Name is cell b3 which is a list

Comment: @ChrisR see edit.  It is now referring to the change in B3 not B5 as the trigger.  Though B5 changes it is changed by a formula and will not trigger the change event.